# In a 2D array, how to shift a row according to a condition on a certain element?

Tags: c

So, I have the 2D array

```
-1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 -1 0 0 1
0 0 -1 0 0 1 1
0 -1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I need to find (a[i][j]== -1) and after that, compare if j=i ; if it doesn't, I need to move the -1 with the whole row to the row where j will be equal to i , so the result will be

```
-1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 -1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 -1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 -1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've thought about several methods, but some of them don't work, and some I don't know how to program, maybe you can give me an idea?(I'm using functions)
This is the last thing I've tried

```
void swap(int **a, int n, int m)
{
    int tem;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i != j && a[i][j] == -1) {
                for (int q = 0; q < n; q++) {
                    for (int w = 0; w < n; w++) {
                        for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {
                            tem = a[q][w];
                            a[q][w] = a[k][w];
                            a[k][w] = tem;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably start with `void swaprows(int a[8][7], int r1, int r2);`

Comment: What didn't work? Please post your attempt so far.

Comment: I'll write it in the question

Comment: You don't have a 2d array.

Comment: I think that a simple approach at this would be to start with a function that returns the position of the first `-1`, aka its column, in a row, or `-1` if it isn't in the row, then another function that swaps any two rows of the matrix if they're not the samerow. The you'd have to sort the rows based on the position of the first `-1`

Comment: Wow -- that's a lot of nesting.

Comment: "This is the last thing I've tried" And in which way does it not work? What are the symptoms? Pleae make a [mre] demonstrating them. Ideally without relying on input, e.g. use hardocded initialised sample data in suitable variables. Is it only the last thing you tried or your best result?

Answer (score 0):

(*I will answer according to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) , i.e. at least at first intentionally not completly.*)

Here are some hints on how to approach:

- You state "I need to find `(a[i][j]== -1)`", but I think that is misleading you into the unhelpful multiple nested loops. Better think like "I each row I need to reorder based on the position of the -1. I.e. better :I need to find a[current_row][j]== -1).
- "... and **after** that, compare if j=i", the "after" is importat. The code you show does the comparing **while** still search through all the elements in a row. Better (in each row) first search for the -1, then stop searching, make a note of the position you found the -1 at and do the implementation of the reorderingoutside/after the loop you used for finding it.
- One of the comments (by Jack Lilhammers) proposes to do the above in a function. That will probably help you separating the parts.
- It seems to me that you attempt to do the reordering of what I expect to be a single row in a triple nested loop construct. Please get a suitable number of different coins to represent one row and line them up, one heads up, the others reverse. Now reorder them so that the head is on the right position (use a die to determine the right position). Observe yourself and try to spot the loops you are doing. You might need two nested loops at first. But if you decide to do it twenty times you will soon come up with a solution to only use one loop. Then try to program that.